# How can I give separate events to buttons in datagridview?

Tags: c#

```
            dgvaciklamaBtn.Name = "Açıklama";
            dgvaciklamaBtn.HeaderText = "Açıklama";
            dgvkartvizitBtn.HeaderText = "Kartvizit";
            dgvaciklamaBtn.Name = "Oku";
            dgvaciklamaBtn.Text = "Oku";
            dgvkartvizitBtn.Text = "Görüntüle";
            dgvaciklamaBtn.UseColumnTextForButtonValue = true;
            dgvkartvizitBtn.UseColumnTextForButtonValue = true;
            dgvaciklamaBtn.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
            dgvkartvizitBtn.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
            dgvaciklamaBtn.DefaultCellStyle.SelectionBackColor = Color.White;
            dgvkartvizitBtn.DefaultCellStyle.SelectionBackColor = Color.White;
            dgvaciklamaBtn.Width = 70;
            dgvkartvizitBtn.Width = 70;
            firmalardtgview.DataSource = firmalartablo;
            firmalardtgview.Columns[0].Width = 30;
            firmalardtgview.Columns.Add(dgvaciklamaBtn);
            firmalardtgview.Columns.Add(dgvkartvizitBtn);
            firmalardtgview.Refresh();
        
     private void firmalardtgview_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e){
        var senderGrid = (DataGridView)sender;
        if (e.ColumnIndex == firmalardtgview.Columns["Açıklama"].Index)
        {
            string firmaid = firmalardtgview.CurrentRow.Cells["ID"].Value.ToString();
            int index = firmaidler.IndexOf(firmaid);
            MessageBox.Show(aciklamalar[index].ToString(), "Açıklama");
        }
```

}

I want to make separate codes for read and explanation. Should I create separate events? Can it be solved with an if query? i am getting error like this

Comment: Where are read and explanation in this snippet? What error are you getting? What have you tried so far? What doesn't work?

Comment: I created two buttons to show the description and business card information in each line of the datagridview. The description button prints the description, but the business card button does the same. I want two separate buttons to do two separate actions.

Comment: System.NullReferenceException
  HResult=0x80004003
  İleti=Nesne başvurusu bir nesnenin örneğine ayarlanmadı.
  Kaynak=TedarikYonetimi
  StackTrace:
   at TedarikYonetimi.FirmaListele.firmalardtgview_CellContentClick(Object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e) in C:\Users\u\source\repos\TedarikYonetimi\TedarikYonetimi\FirmaListele.cs:line 149
I get this error

Comment: var senderGrid = (DataGridView)sender;
            if (senderGrid.Columns[e.ColumnIndex] is DataGridViewButtonColumn && e.RowIndex >= 0 )
            //if (e.ColumnIndex == firmalardtgview.Columns["Oku"].Index)
            {
                string firmaid = firmalardtgview.CurrentRow.Cells["ID"].Value.ToString();
                int index = firmaidler.IndexOf(firmaid);
                MessageBox.Show(aciklamalar[index].ToString(), "Açıklama");
            }     this code works all buttons with same task

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by taking the index number of the column and comparing it with the index number of the selected column.
It would be better if there is another shortcut. This is how it works.

```
      string kartismi="";
        if (e.ColumnIndex == 0)
        {
            string firmaid = firmalardtgview.CurrentRow.Cells["ID"].Value.ToString();
            int index = firmaidler.IndexOf(firmaid);
            MessageBox.Show(aciklamalar[index].ToString(), "Açıklama");
        }
        else if (e.ColumnIndex == 1)
        {
            string firmaid = firmalardtgview.CurrentRow.Cells["ID"].Value.ToString();
            int index = firmaidler.IndexOf(firmaid);
            SqlBaglanti.baglanti.Open();
            SqlCommand kartvizitisimi = new SqlCommand("SELECT kartvizit_ismi FROM kartvizitler WHERE kartvizit_id=@kid", SqlBaglanti.baglanti);
            kartvizitisimi.Parameters.AddWithValue("@kid", kartvizitIDler[index]);
            SqlDataReader dr = kartvizitisimi.ExecuteReader();
            if(dr.Read())
            {
                kartismi = dr["kartvizit_ismi"].ToString();
            }
            SqlBaglanti.baglanti.Close();

            Process.Start(Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath,"Kartvizitler",kartismi));
        }
```